# Django find max on a join

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Data(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
    metric = models.IntegerField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source)
```

I want to find all the sources which don't have any data points in the last three days. In PostgreSQL, this is doable:

```
select influence_source.src, max(influence_data.date) as max_date
from influence_data, influence_source
where influence_data.source_id = influence_source.id
group by influence_source.src
having max(influence_data.date) < now()::date - 7
order by max_date;
```

Is this possible using Django's ORM?

I've tried:

```
>> Source.objects.raw("select influence_source.src, max(influence_data.date) as max_date from influence_data, influence_source where influence_data.source_id = influence_source.id group by influence_source.src having max(influence_data.date) < now()::date - 7 order by max_date")
<RawQuerySet: 'select influence_source.src, max(influence_data.date) as max_date from influence_data, influence_source where influence_data.source_id = influence_source.id group by influence_source.src having max(influence_data.date) < now()::date - 7 order by max_date'>
>> list(_)
InvalidQuery: Raw query must include the primary key
```

(Adding the primary key gives `DatabaseError: column "influence_source.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`)

I've read the [aggregation docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/), but it's not obvious to me how I can do this query:

```
>> Source.objects.all().aggregate(Max('data__date'))
{'data__date__max': datetime.date(2012, 11, 16)} # a single result was not what I wanted
```

How do I find all the source objects whose most recent data object is more than three days old? I have a lot of data, so I want to do a single DB query instead of iterating over objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime

three_days_ago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(3)
Source.objects.annotate(max_date=Max('data__date')).exclude(max_date__gt=three_days_ago).order_by('max_date')
```